# Задать несколькольким ключам в словаре одинаковое значение

Tags: python, pandas

При подгрузке cvs файла указываю типы данных столбцов. Так как многие столбцы имеют одинаковый тип, хотелось бы разом указать один тип для них всех.
Сейчас делаю так:

```
dict_type={'col1': int, 'col2':int, 'col3':int}
```

Хотел бы что-то типо такого:

```
dict_type={['col1', 'col2', 'col3']:int}
```

Comment: а какие типы данных в вашем файле pandas распознаёт неверно?

Comment: дело не в том, что неверно, просто хочу сэкономить по памяти и скорости за счёт точного указания типов данных. Столбцов много и приходится каждому столбцу в ручном режиме указывать. мне показалось это странным - невозможность как-то эффективно указать размерности всех столбцов.

Comment: дело как раз в том, что, возможно, ничего не нужно указывать, и pandas сам верно определяет нужные типы данных.

Comment: не, я имею ввиду, что к примеру тип данных int - пандас правильно определяет, а я хочу указать int8. и по остальным столбцам тоже самое  - более точно указать

Comment: @strawdog А, я понял, это "маленькие хитрости" с Каггла для экономии памяти, когда датасет большой, данных много, но они влезают в какие-то маленькие диапазоны. Такое бывает не просто автоматом подобрать, а сам `Pandas` такое вообще не умеет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```py
dict_type = dict.fromkeys(('col1', 'col2', 'col3'), int)
```

Если нужно несколько разных типов, то чуть сложнее:

```py
dict_type = dict.fromkeys(('col1', 'col2', 'col3'), int)
dict_type.update(dict.fromkeys(('col4', 'col5', 'col6'), float))
```

Ещё вариант со словарным сокращением:

```py
dict_type = {key:val for items, val in (
                (('col1', 'col2', 'col3'), int), 
                (('col4', 'col5', 'col6'), float)
            ) for key in items}
```

Comment: а можно как-то за один раз "на месте" для разных типов задать... ?

Comment: @Alexandr Добавил ещё один вариант